# up voting should be closed after accepted answer

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, upvotes

Up voting should be closed (should not be allowed further) after accepting the answer. It can be allowed to star (make it as favourite question) even after making the accepting the answer.

Comment: And what is your **reasoning** for requesting such a feature? A feature request is largely meaningless if there isn't any reason behind it or discussion about its benefits.

Comment: Downvotes on meta can in very many cases mean that people are disagreeing with your proposal.

Comment: After accepting answer, it shows the question is completed with answer. downvote can be enabled but no upvote.

Comment: No. Accepting an answer means the questioner has found their solution. It doesn't mean the question cannot have other solutions, or better solutions.

Comment: Your proposal is very radical. Maybe you have some serious arguments to this. If so then share with us and give as a chance to upvote you.

Comment: up vote encourages to find the answer, hence i think no need to encourage further to find answer more because user might have accepted   the same

Comment: What's the benefit that such a feature would bring?

Comment: Up votes do no such thing. Upvotes on the question simply mean *Good question, well researched, I had this problem too but you asked it already*, etc. If accepting means no more voting is allowed on the question, ***no one will accept answers anymore***.

Comment: Do you think a question on SO is only for the person who asked it? What about all the other people who might find the quesiton relevant and might want to vote for it and the answers? What about all the cases where the answer chosen by OP is by far not the best one? Your proposal is complete nonsense and you don't seem to understand SO or the SE network at all. Furthermore, it's even unclear _what_ should be restricted - question votes, answer votes, all of them?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Your point is correct. While reviewing triage the system sometime automatically make us to vote by saying "upvote encourages to find the answer".

Comment: @Exhausted: yes, by increasing visibility. But where does it say that you then should **stop** finding answers? If someone builds a better mousetrap, won't you want to know?

Comment: some one has made my quesion to downvote in SO.

Comment: how do you suggest things to work in case if asker unaccepts? would you expect upvotes to become allowed again or remain forbidden?

Comment: Its just a suggestion i made, might be unclear of something i had.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I disagree. Users should have the ability to vote on posts, no matter whether it has an accepted answer or not. Why? Because if the question has an accepted answer and is helpful, I'd like to upvote the question because it's helpful. That's a positive sign towards the original poster. And I also want to be able to downvote questions with an accepted answer. Having an accepted answer does not mean "this question is high-quality"; votes are a better indicator for that.